# Doesn't save data django Foreignkey model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I've two model. I would like to save data from ForeignKey model. I'm created a modelform and save with my main foreignkey model.  But I got this error `ValueError at /c/customer/1/
Cannot assign "'1'": "BillingData.customer" must be a "CustomerData" instance.`

I created Django model form and hocked up with view.

models.py file

```py
class CustomerData(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    customer_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField()
    alternative_phone = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    union_name = models.ForeignKey(UnionName, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    word_name = models.ForeignKey(UnionWordName, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    full_address = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, Mobile: %s' % (self.customer_name, self.mobile_number)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('customer_data', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


class BillingData(models.Model):
    bill_no = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True)

    customer = models.ForeignKey(CustomerData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sales_person = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    customer_money = models.IntegerField()
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.customer.customer_name, self.create_date.date())

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('customers.views.BillingPage', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

forms.py file

```py
class BillCreateForms(forms.ModelForm):
    bill_no = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    customer = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[(x.id, x.customer_name) for x in CustomerData.objects.all()])
    customer_money = forms.IntegerField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(BillCreateForms, self).save(commit=False)
        customer_pk = self.cleaned_data['customer']

        instance.customer = CustomerData.objects.get(pk=customer_pk)
        instance.save(commit)
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = BillingData
        fields = ('bill_no', 'customer', 'customer_money',)
```

views.py file

```
class CustomerDataView(FormMixin, generic.DetailView):
    model = CustomerData
    form_class = BillCreateForms
    template_name = "customers/customerdata_detail.html"
    print(form_class)

    success_url = '/c/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

I expect data save with foreignkey relation data. But doesn't save here.

Comment: The code you have posted shouldn't give that error. Show the full traceback.

Comment: this is full traceback https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Z92rVxJpnJ/

Answer (score 1):

You can't fix this problem in the save method, because the error happens before it gets that far.

You should be using a ModelChoiceField, not a ChoiceField. Not only would this fix the problem, it would also let you remove your entire save method.

```
customer = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=CustomerData.objects.all())
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
instance.customer = CustomerData.objects.get(pk=customer_pk)
```

to

```
instance.customer_id = CustomerData.objects.get(pk=customer_pk).pk
```

Comment: same issue created ``` Cannot assign "'1'": "BillingData.customer" must be a "CustomerData" instance.```

Comment: @AsaduzzamanSohel: The error means that you need to get the customer object out of the database and then use that object instead of the object's id. You need to figure out what's in customer_pk b/c it looks like it might be more than just customer.id. Once you know where pk is, use it to get a CustomerData object to assign to instance.customer

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Set object

```
b = Blog.objects.get(id=1)
e = Entry.objects.get(id=234)
b.entry_set.add(e)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).